# Facebook, Check user authorization to app without prompt

Tags: facebook, authentication, authorization, facebook-php-sdk

I want to have a "remember me" access to my web app with facebook authorization, and check if the user has authorized my app without asking the user for permissions.

I want to ask a new user from facebook for authorization only if the user starts the registration process not just to check for authorization in a first access.

How can I do it?

Comment: Post your code, then we can modify it to work as you wish

Comment: It's not a question about my code. I've not code about it. I have the code that redirects user to facebook authentication/authorization page and returns it to my page and it works fine. If the user has not authorized my app, facebook ask for permission. I don't want the user to be asked if the registration process is not started by the user.

Comment: I'm sorry but SO doesn't work that way! post your code ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option is not available through the OAuth URL. I was using Facebook SDK for PHP and the solution is to use it in conjunction with the Facebook SDK for javascript:

> `FB.getLoginStatus` allows you to determine if a user is logged in to Facebook and has authenticated your app. There are three possible states for a user:
>
> - the user is **logged into Facebook and has authenticated your
>     application** (connected)
> - the user is **logged into Facebook but has not authenticated your application** (not_authorized)
> - the user is **not logged into Facebook** at this time and so we don't know if they've authenticated your application or not (unknown)
>
> With social application, knowing which of the these three states the user is in is one of the first things your application needs to know upon page load.