# How to check if a user has already authorized an app in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, titanium, facebook-fql

Before make the app ask for authorization, i've tried to make an fql request to get user parameters (at least those allowed by the basic permission) in order to check if he has already authorized the app once (users who have authorized the app i will store their names on a cookies for example and i will compare the fql request result with their list..) but i couldn't get anything from that fql request. i think now by also reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425235/facebook-check-user-authorization-to-app-without-prompt) that it is not possible to know that.. any clue ?

I'm not asking to know wether user has authorized the app in real time but in the past even before being logged in and then out.

Answer (score 0):

When you authorise your app, the user must first login on facebook, and that's means that you can check if the user is logged in or not, if not, that doesn't mean he hasn't authorised the app before, but if yes, then of course the app is authorised, maybe it's not what you exactly want, but I think it does the job.

```
if(Facebook.loggedIn) {
   alert("Must be authorised before");
}
else {
   alert("If this is the first time, the app is not authorised yet.");
}
```

By the way, don't logout from facebook until you need to, so you're always authorised and can request what you want anytime during the app.

Comment: I've tested the case in which user has authorized the app in the past but facebook.loggedIn = false.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can query the [**user**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) table and check for the value of `is_app_user`.

```
SELECT is_app_user FROM user WHERE uid = 'USER-ID'
```

But the thing is that where exactly would you like to check this? After login itself you can get to know whether the user has authorized the app or not!

Comment: i think i already tried is_app_user but doesn't help and i want to check if user has already authorized the app when he tries to login with facebook to the app so that if he has already authorized he will only be logged in the app without getting a new request for authorizing in facebook.

Comment: Well, you don't have to check this , facebook handles this by themselves. If the user has already authorized your app before, he will not be prompted again for the authorization while login!

Comment: all my problem comes from mixing login into my app with facebook login  which is indeed a request for app authorization and shouldn't occurs each time the user wants to login into the app using credentials coming from that request (requests could always have results if the user never logout but this is not ensured in my app).  i have to seperate them..